# Android location services crashes the app randomly when it is in the paused state

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I have defined a service which runs in the background which requests location updates every 5 minutes. The app crashes intermittently when it is in the paused state(i.e. runs in the background) or I get this error message on the device "Unfortunately google play services has stopped working". I presume its because the app is requesting location updates even the the app is paused which is something I do not want.

I have added my service in this gist as it is too long to paste here

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/214f8fe6948314a2d043

How do you suggest I make sure my app does not randomly crash due to those location updates. Is there a way I can pause the location updates when the app is paused? I had read online that it could be due to a memory leak, what do you all think? I start my service in the LAUNCHER activity and this service is supposed to run in all the other activities that are supposed to be loaded.

Comment: can you provide error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the on pause of your activity, remove location updates of the location listener like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Onpause", 0).show();
    super.onPause();
    location_manager.removeUpdates(YourActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: the Service class does not have an onPause to override, also if you are implying that I call the removeUpdates, if you check the gist I have attached I am using the         LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this); which is called from inside my Service class, so how can I get a context of that Service which is running and call the removeLocationUpdates, and is that the way to go?